# Adding new line in printf() or format()

Tags: java, formatting, printf

today I was reading in the java Tutorials docs from Oracle about [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) and I encountered  `println()` vs `printf()` vs `format()` after I understood the differences I read the following sentence which makes no sense for me.

> A new line character appropriate to the platform running the application. You should always use %n, rather than \n.

so the main question of this is why "should" I always use `%n` instead of `\n` what difference does this make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The %n is like a placeholder for whatever the newline character may be for a particular system. %n could very well be \n for a specific system or \r\n for another such as the case with windows. Using %n is the safer alternative to typing \n because as @user85421 commented, some windows applications don't recognize \n.